# passing JSON array between two web sites

Tags: php, json, curl

I want to pass an array between two websites but i have difficult to do that,in my localhost i try this code :

```
 $array = array("12" => "val", "34" => "val2");
 $url = 'http://example1.com/save.php';
 $post = 'data='.json_encode($array);
 $ch = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
 curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
```

then in example1.com/save.php i do this just for testing:

```
 $result = json_decode($_POST['data'],true);

 foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.'='.$value.'<br />';
 }
```

but this give me this warning:

```
  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/a2549384/public_html/save.php on line 5
```

is there any solution?

Comment: What's the value of `$_POST['data']`? Apparently something went wrong ;)

Comment: insert `print_r($result)` in the middle of your code to make sure it's actually an associative array.

Comment: if i do echo $_POST['data']; the output is like this :{\"1923654\":\"3 - 0\",\"9874587\":\"0 - 0\"}

Comment: @  Blazemonger print_r($result) not show any thing.

Comment: You probably don't have a valid JSON object. You need to unescape those quote marks. Why do you need `data=` anyway?

Comment: Have a look at [json_last_error](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) and http://jsonlint.com. If @Blazemonger that might be valid if save.php expects a form response containing JSON.

Comment: you've got magic_quotes enabled. update your php to something less idiotically stupidly old...

Answer (score 0):

You should check that what you are passing to foreach is an array by using the [is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) function. Error means you are doing a foreach on something that is not an array.

Check out your foreach and look if the thing before the as is actually an array. Not only in theory but actually use [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to dump it.

Also If you are not sure it's going to be an array you can always check using the following PHP example code:

```
if (is_array($variable)) {

  foreach ($variable as $item) {
   //do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change

`$post = 'data='.json_encode($array);`

to

`$post = 'data='.urlencode(json_encode($array));`

In any case, just `var_dump($_POST);` on the other side and see if there are encoding errors.

With `json_last_error()` you can check if there was an error in decoding.

Comment: this is what i get :array(1) { ["data"]=> string(45) "{\"1923654\":\"3 - 0\",\"9874587\":\"0 - 0\"}" }

Comment: That looks like valid JSON. What does `json_decode` give you?

Comment: $result = json_decode($_POST['data']);

var_dump($result); output = NULL;